# Sorting items by drag and drop in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, jquery-ui

In my django project I show a list of books in template. **Book** model has **position** field which I use to sort books.

I'm trying to sort this list by drag and drop list items but my next code dont work well. I use **JQuery UI**. It works in frontend but dont change position field`s value when user drag and drop list item. Can someone help me to improve my js and view code. I am comfused. I would be grateful for any help.

**models.py:**

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Заголовок', blank=False)
    position = models.IntegerField(help_text='Поле для сортировки', default=0, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position', 'pk']
```

**html:**

```
<div id="books" class="list-group">
{% for book in books %}
  <div class="panel panel-default list-group-item ui-state-default">
    <div class="panel-body">{{ book.title }}</div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^book/(?P<pk>\d+)/sorting/$',
     BookSortingView.as_view(),
     name='book_sorting')
```

**JS:**

```
$("#books").sortable({
      update: function(event, ui) {
            var information = $('#books').sortable('serialize');
            $.ajax({
                  url: "???",
                  type: "post",
                  data: information
            });
      },
}).disableSelection();
```

**views.py:**

```
class BookSortingView(View):
    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(BookSortingView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        for index, pk in enumerate(request.POST.getlist('book[]')):
            book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=pk)
            book.position = index
            book.save()
        return HttpResponse()
```

Comment: I would suggest employing some debugging to pinpoint the error. Does the ajax method post the correct data -> use `console.log()`. Does it get posted to the right URL -> `'???'` can't be right. Does the python view get the parameter -> use `print`. Etc etc

Comment: @RoyPrins my problem is I dont know well what exactly I need to put in that ajax's url. I tried to `url: "{% url 'book_sorting' %}"` but it`s wrong. In temninal it shows 404. JS dont understand it. For thats I am confused how to put url correctly. What can you advice to me?

Comment: "{% url 'book_sorting' %}" in your case really does not exist
your url is '^book/(?P<pk>\d+)/sorting/$' so you need pass pk argument to url tag. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: also there is an library https://github.com/jrief/django-admin-sortable2.
It makes what you want but only in a admin interface. But you can check their solution.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. There are a lot of libraries to sort items by drag and drop in admin. But i need to use it outside of admin. Anyway Thank You! =)

Answer (score 5):

This is working for me!!

**JS**

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("tbody").sortable({
         update: function(event, ui) {
            sort =[];
            window.CSRF_TOKEN = "{{ csrf_token }}";
            $("tbody").children().each(function(){
                sort.push({'pk':$(this).data('pk'),'order':$(this).index()})

        });


        $.ajax({
          url: "{% url "book-sort" %}
",
          type: "post",
          datatype:'json',
          data:{'sort':JSON.stringify(sort),
           'csrfmiddlewaretoken': window.CSRF_TOKEN
          },

        });
         console.log(sort)
          },
        }).disableSelection();
      });
```

**HTML**

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="sortable" style="">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>

    </thead>
    <tbody id="#Table">
        {% for book in books %}

        <tr data-pk="{{ book.id }}" class="ui-state-default" style="cursor: move;" data-placement="left"  title="Customize the order by drag and drop">
        <td> <a>{{ book.name }}</a> </td>


        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

**view**

```
@csrf_exempt
def sort(self):
    books = json.loads(self.request.POST.get('sort'))
    for b in books:
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=int(b['pk']))
        book.position = b['order']
        book.save()
    return HttpResponse('saved')
```

**and also change the query_set in your listview to get the books in that order**

```
 books = Book.objects.all().order_by('position')
```

Comment: i'm try to use your function in my view so i'm getting this `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'` error would you like to tell me how can i solve this issue ?

Comment: To avoid the AttributeError above try:

def sort(request):
    books = json.loads(request.POST.get('sort'))
    for b in books:
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, pk=int(b['pk']))
        book.position = b['order']
        book.save()
    return HttpResponse('saved')