# How to Reorder the position of objects in Django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-views

The code below is getting error `AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'`. I want to reOrder the position of objects using JQuery sortable.js Drag and drop.
the drag and drop frontend is working fine but when my code try to save the object position i'm getting the error `'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'`. I would be grateful for any help.

```
@csrf_exempt
def sort(self):
    books = json.loads(self.request.POST.get('sort'))
    for b in books:
        book = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=int(b['pk']))
        book.position = b['order']
        book.save()
    return HttpResponse('saved')
```

html

```
<table class="table" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 0;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Story</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Timestamp</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for object in articles %}
        <tr data-pk="{{ object.id }}">
            <td>{{ object.id }}</td>
            <td><a href="">{{ object.title }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ object.author.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ object.updated_on | naturaltime }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

js

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("tbody").sortable({
            update: function (event, ui) {
                sort = [];
                window.CSRF_TOKEN = "{{ csrf_token }}";
                $("tbody").children().each(function () {
                    sort.push({ 'pk': $(this).data('pk'), 'order': $(this).index() })
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'rundown-sort' %}",
                    type: "post",
                    datatype: 'json',
                    data: {
                        'sort': JSON.stringify(sort),
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': window.CSRF_TOKEN
                    },
                    success: function () {
                        console.log('success')
                    }
                });
                console.log(sort)
            },
        }).disableSelection();
    });
```

Comment: Do you want to reorder them in the database or just when you're displaying them?

Comment: Can you show the class which this method is written in? The error implies that the class self may be a request object here.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat it's not a class it is a function dear. [This is what is want to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59580747/14182249)

Comment: Then the answer given by Sirwill98 solves your error. For the error with the pk you would need to show your js template

Comment: my Question is updated please take a look... now it getting Error `the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType`

Comment: You are selecting the tbody tag directly! give an id to the tag and select that id, there might be other tbody tags in your html causing unintended behaviour. Also to be on the safe side you should not render using django inside your js code, put the urls / csrf on a html tag as a data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this? (replacing self with request and using request instead of self.request

```
@csrf_exempt
def sort(request):
    books = json.loads(request.POST.get('sort'))
    for b in books:
        book = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=int(b['pk']))
        book.position = b['order']
        book.save()
    return HttpResponse('saved')
```

Comment: yes i also try this! when i try with your code it's getting `keyError` `Exception Value: 'pk'`

Comment: it seems like the line `book = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=int(b['pk']))` is throwing the error, what does the json look like?

Comment: here is the json looks like [{'order': 0}, {'order': 1}, {'pk': 51, 'order': 0}, {'pk': 59, 'order': 1}, {'pk': 61, 'order': 2}, {'pk': 62, 'order': 3}, {'pk': 63, 'order': 4}, {'pk': 65, 'order': 5}, {'pk': 64, 'order': 6}, {'pk': 66, 'order': 7}, {'pk': 67, 'order': 8}]

Comment: i think this error is because the first 2 json entries have no value of PK, can you do an if statement to check for a pk

Comment: would you like explain how can i use if statement in my function?

Comment: or if you don't mind and define if statement into my function

Comment: `try:
       book = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=int(b['pk']))
        book.position = b['order']
        book.save()
    except KeyError:
        pass`

Comment: new lines dont appear in comments but large blank spaces are new lines